# Summarizing multiple columns based on one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, plyr

I have a data frame which looks something like this:

| TCGA_Name | Full_Name | Gene.Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thyroid Carcinoma | Papillary Thyroid Cancer | NRAS |
| Thyroid Carcinoma | Thyroid Gland Carcinoma | NRAS |
| Sarcoma | Uterine leiomyosarcoma | PIK3CA |
| Sarcoma | Sarcoma | PIK3CA |
| Ovarian Serous Cystadenocarcinoma | High Grade Serous Ovarian Cancer | PIK3CA |

What I'm trying to reduce the number of rows based on TCGA_Name. I want to Full_Name cancer types if they have the same TCGA heading and share their gene.name. The final product should look like this:

| TCGA_Name | Full_Name | Gene.Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thyroid Carcinoma | Papillary Thyroid Cancer, Thyroid Gland Carcinoma | NRAS |
| Sarcoma | Uterine leiomyosarcoma, Sarcoma | PIK3CA |
| Ovarian Serous Cystadenocarcinoma | High Grade Serous Ovarian Cancer | PIK3CA |

so far I've managed this:

````
library(plyr) 
df1 <- ddply(df1, .(TCGA_Name), summarize, text=paste(Hotspot_Name, collapse=", "))```
````

but this deletes the `Gene.Name` column

as always, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
df1 <- ddply(df1, .(TCGA_Name,Gene.Name), summarize, text=paste(Full_Name, collapse=", "))
```

Just add **'Gene.Name'**